# React Native expo Unable to resolve .. from

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

I'm starting to develop an app in react native but I have an issue.

I want to use absolute path but it doesn't work.

I have this error : Unable to resolve "infrastructure/controllers/AppControllers" from "src\infrastructure\ui\pages\App.tsx"

Here is my architecture :
[Archi](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kM2Ti.png)

my tsconfig.json :

```
{
  "extends": "expo/tsconfig.base",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "strict": true,
    "baseUrl": "./src"
  }
}
```

and my babel.config.js :

```
module.exports = function (api) {
  api.cache(true);
  return {
    presets: ['module:metro-react-native-babel-preset'],
    plugins: [
      [
        'babel-plugin-root-import',
        {
          paths: [
            {
              rootPathSuffix: './src',
              rootPathPrefix: 'src',
            },
          ]
        },
      ],
    ],
  };
};
```

I really don't understand why this is not working

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't mentioned what absolute path your are trying to configure. For exemple, for a `~/*` resolver, consider doing:

**tsconfig.json**

```json
{
  "extends": "expo/tsconfig.base",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "strict": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "~/*": ["src/*"]
    }
  }
}
```

**babel.config.js**

```js
module.exports = function (api) {
  api.cache(true);
  return {
    presets: ["babel-preset-expo"],
    plugins: [
      [
        "module-resolver",
        {
          alias: {
            "~": "./src",
          },
        },
      ],
    ],
  };
};
```